# Dexie.js - ordering with more than one index

Tags: dexie

I am using dexie.js to interface with IndexedDB. I am wondering if it is possible to orderby or sortby using more than one index at once (eg. db.people.orderBy( index1, desc : index2, asc )...
If it is possible, what is the correct syntax?

Answer (score 1):

Either use compound indexes, or use Collection.and().

If you can live with only targeting Chrome, Firefox or Opera, you can use compound indexes. If it must work on Safari, IndexedDBShim, Edge or IE, you cannot use compound indexes today. There's a [shim](https://github.com/dfahlander/idb-iegap) that enables it for IE/Edge though, but it is still in beta, so I would recommend to instead use Collection.and() for those cases.

Let' say you have a form where users can fill in various attributes of friends:

```
<form>
  <input name="name"/>
  <input name="age"/>
  <input name="shoeSize" />
</form>
```

#### Using Collection.and()

First, pick the most probably index to start your search on. In this case, "name" would be a perfect index that wouldn't match so many items, while age or shoeSize would probably match more friends.

Schema:

```
db.version(X).stores({
    friends: "id, name, age, shoeSize"
});
```

Query:

```
function prepareQuery () {
    // Pick a good index. The picked index will filter out with IndexedDB's built-in keyrange
    var query;
    if (form.name.value) {
        query = db.friends.where('name').equals(form.name.value);
    } else if (form.age.value) {
        query = db.friends.where('age').equals(parseInt(form.age.value));
    } else if (form.shoeSize.value) {
        query = db.friends.where('shoeSize').equals(parseInt(form.shoeSize.value));
    } else {
        query = db.friends.toCollection();
    }

    // Then manually filter the result. May filter a field that the DB has already filtered out,
    // but the time that takes is negligible.
    return query.and (function (friend) {
        return (
            (!form.name.value || friend.name === form.name.value) &&
            (!form.age.value || friend.age == form.age.value) &&
            (!form.shoeSize.value || friend.shoeSize == form.shoeSize.value));
    });
}

// Run the query:
form.onsubmit = function () {
    prepareQuery() // Returns a Collection
        .limit(25) // Optionally add a limit onto the Collection
        .toArray(function (result) { // Execute query
            alert (JSON.stringify(result, null, 4));
        })
        .catch (function (e) {
            alert ("Oops: " + e);
        });
}
```

#### Using compound indexes

As written above, compound indexes code will only work on mozilla- and chromium based browsers.

```
db.version(x).stores({
    friends: "id, name, age, shoeSize," +
        "[name+age+shoeSize]," +
        "[name+shoeSize]," +
        "[name+age]," +
        "[age+shoeSize]"
});
```

The prepareQuery() function when using compound indexes:

```
function prepareQuery() {
    var indexes = []; // Array of Array[index, key]
    if (form.name.value)
        indexes.push(["name", form.name.value]);
    if (form.age.value)
        indexes.push(["age", parseInt(form.age.value)]);
    if (form.shoeSize.value)
        indexes.push(["shoeSize", parseInt(form.shoeSize.value)]);

    var index = indexes.map(x => x[0]).join('+'),
        keys = indexes.map(x => x[1]);

    if (indexes.length === 0) {
        // No field filled in. Return unfiltered Collection
        return db.friends.toCollection();
    } else if (indexes.length === 1) {
        // Single field filled in. Use simple index:
        return db.friends.where(index).equals(keys[0]);
    } else {
        // Multiple fields filled in. Use compound index:
        return db.friends.where("[" + index + "]").equals(keys);
    }
}

// Run the query:
form.onsubmit = function () {
    prepareQuery() // Returns a Collection
        .limit(25) // Optionally add a limit onto the Collection
        .toArray(function (result) { // Execute query
            alert (JSON.stringify(result, null, 4));
        })
        .catch (function (e) {
            alert ("Oops: " + e);
        });
}
```

*Using arrow functions here to make it more readable. Also, you're targeting chromium or firefox and they support it already.*

Comment: Where does the ordering come in?

Comment: @BenjaminH did you got the solution ?

Comment: Sorry, dropped this a while back.

Comment: Hi @davidfahlander ! thank you for sharing this. I'm far from being a JS expert but I see filtering not ordering here, right?

Comment: IndexedDB is a low level database the returns the result in the order of the queried index. When filtering on an index the result will also be ordered by the same. To get ordering only, you can enumerate an entire range of an index. Dexie has a `sortBy` method that can perform sorting on alternate property than the indexed one. In this particular answer I suppose I was trying to utilize the index for both sorting and filtering.